# Finding k non contiguous random numbers with uniform probability in the range 1..n

Tags: python, random, probability

I am trying to find `k` random numbers in the range `1..n` such that none of the `k` numbers are contiguous. The code I came up with is

```
def noncontiguoussample(n,k):
    import random
    numbers = range(n)
    samples = []
    for _ in range(k):
        v = random.choice(numbers)
        samples.append(v)
        for v in range(v-1, v+2):
            try:
                numbers.remove(v)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    return samples
```

*Update: I know this function won't return the samples with uniform probability. Based on my limited testing, Amber's solution below satisfies both the condition (a) individual elements of the sample are non-contiguous, and (b) all possible k samples (from 1...n) are generated with uniform probability.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is simpler if you use a `set`.

```
import random

def noncontiguoussample(n,k):
    numbers = set(range(1,n+1))
    samples = []
    for _ in range(k):
        v = random.choice(list(numbers))
        samples.append(v)
        numbers -= set([v-1, v, v+1])
    return samples
```

However, as Michael Anderson points out in the comments, this algorithm can fail sometimes in cases where `n < 3*k`.

---

**A better algorithm that can't fail (and is also faster!) might look like this:**

```
import random

def noncontiguoussample(n,k):
    # How many numbers we're not picking
    total_skips = n - k

    # Distribute the additional skips across the range
    skip_cutoffs = random.sample(range(total_skips+1), k)
    skip_cutoffs.sort()

    # Construct the final set of numbers based on our skip distribution
    samples = []
    for index, skip_spot in enumerate(skip_cutoffs):
        # This is just some math-fu that translates indices within the
        # skips to values in the overall result.
        samples.append(1 + index + skip_spot)

    return samples
```

The math-fu at the end there is this:

- 1, the minimum value we can pick
- plus 1 per number we've picked (`index`), to account for that picked number
- plus our position within the skips (which will always increase by at least one)

Thus the result will always increase by at least 2 for each iteration through the loop.

Comment: There's a nasty edge case where this will crash some of the time. Select 2 "random" non-contiguous values from 1,2,3. You should always get `{1,3}`. With this code you get a crash most of the time.

Comment: I suspect that a similar issue means that the results coming from this algorithm (and the original) exhibit some bias. (You may or may not care about such things, but its worth being aware of).

Comment: v = random.choice(list(numbers))

Comment: @Amber.. That is nice solution.. Just want to ask a question.. What is that `underscore(_)` in the for loop contains?? Why we use that??

Comment: @RohitJain It's a placeholder; we don't care about the actual value in the iteration.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson That's true - in cases where `n < 3*k`, this can potentially fail.

Comment: I've added a better algorithm that both can't fail and also has much better distribution.

Comment: Amber, can you clarify: What is the definition of total distance? The code fails at least for n=6 and k =3. Furthermore, I don't think it is selecting all the possible sets of samples either. Try it for n=6 and k=2 and it give only the following combinations: [2,6], [2,5], [3,6], [1,5], [1,4], [1,6]

Comment: @Sumit - there was a bug; I've edited the code to correct it. You can ignore the bit about distances; it was a poor explanation. Basically, the idea is to focus on how many numbers you skip in between the numbers you actually pick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an unbiased version that won't fail. (But is slower than Ambers solution). If you give it a case with no solution it will loop forever (but thats fixable).

```
#A function to check if the given set is OK
def is_valid_choice( s ):
  for x in s:
    if x-1 in s or x+1 in s:
      return False
  return True

#The real function
def noncontiguoussample(n,k):
  while True:
    s = random.sample(xrange(1,n+1),k)
    if is_valid_choice(s):
      return s
```